# Unrecognized root certificatication authority found

Tags: windows-7, certificate, trusted-root-certificates, trusted-root-ca

I was looking at the certificates on my local PC (Win 7 64-bit) and found one in the "trusted root certification authorities" section that has the same "Issued To" and "Issued By" names (as do most of the "trusted roots") --

ME8540724C2B64BF1A77321EAE181CC91

Google has 0 references to this.  It seems likely that this is a fraudulent certificate (whose presence makes me rather unhappy).  Is there a reason to do anything other than delete it?  (I could export it first, making it possible to bring it back.)

Any advice / opinion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't recognize the common name of the certificate, or don't know where it came from, ***delete it***. If it's from a website, it will likely prompt you to accept it again when you revisit anyway.  If this is a work machine you should consult your IT Personnel, but if this is a personal machine, I would just get rid of it and keep going. It's a self signed cert which are questionable to begin with in most cases.